# Is it possible to export widgets from one Workshop module to another?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

What is best practice for Workshop development? We're trying to figure out how to work separately on different modules such that we can merge them later (pretty sure it's not possible to branch Workshop modules).

Two questions:

- Is it possible to export widgets from one Workshop module to another?
- Is it possible to duplicate a Workshop module to create a "develop" version?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible way of exporting a widget from a Workshop module and importing it into another:

1. In your original Workshop module, copy the Raw Widget Configuration of the widget you'd like to export/copy.
2. In your new Workshop module, create a Widget of the same type as the one you want to export.
3. Navigate to the Raw Widget Configuration section in your new widget, and paste in the Raw Widget Configuration from the original widget. Click `Validate and save` to complete the process.

[image: original widget raw widget configuration section]

[image: adding a new markdown widget]

[image: pasting widget configuration into new widget]